# php code or mysql query to calculate days between two dates from database

Tags: php, mysql

table name

receipt

```
id  coupondate    name      recno
1   15-04-2015     A          1
1   15-05-2015     A          1
1   15-06-2015     A          1
1   15-07-2015     A          1
1   15-08-2015     A          1
1   15-09-2015     A          1
```

here  coupondate starts from 15-04-2015 and finished on 15-09-2015..

so i need code which display 1 to all days which comes between 15-04 and 15-09.

**expected output**

```
 15-04 16-04 17-04 18-04 19-04 20-04 21-04 22-04......like wise 15-09
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1                   1


SELECT RE.coupondate FROM receipt_entry RE LEFT JOIN city_master CM ON RE.city_name = CM.id WHERE CM.cityname = :cityname
                AND str_to_date(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm form me.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2010-07-06");
$date2 = new DateTime("2010-07-09");
$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```